# how set a specifc database schema with gorm?

Tags: database, go, database-connection, go-gorm

I'm developing an CRUD app. I'm reading an JSON from an api and I want to write this JSON in a database with "database/sql" and GORM in a spcific schema
the struct:

```
type Veiculo struct {
gorm.Model
Codigo                int       `json:"vei_codigo"`
Placa                 string    `json:"vei_placa"`
Nome                  string    `json:"vei_nome"`
}
```

the endpoint function:

```
func CreateVeiculo(c *gin.Context) {

var veiculo model.Veiculo
//id := c.Params.ByName("id")

c.BindJSON(&veiculo)
c.JSON(200, veiculo)

psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+" password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", host, port, user, password, dbname)
dbVeiculosGorm, err := gorm.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer dbVeiculosGorm.Close()

dbVeiculosGorm.AutoMigrate(&model.Veiculo{})

//t := time.Now()
//ts := t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")

dbVeiculosGorm.Create(&model.Veiculo{Placa: veiculo.Placa, Nome: veiculo.Nome}
```

but the database is untouchable. There is multiple schemas. Do i have to set the specific schema?? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried making a super simple model, migrating it and inserting some data into it?

Comment: @Mihailo
Yes. I tried a simple get and returns an error: column ''columnName" does not exist

Comment: Have you migrated your models? Do they exist in the database?

Comment: Yes. they exist

Comment: You can read up on it [here](http://gorm.io/docs/migration.html). If the tables don't exist there's nowhere for your data to be saved.

Answer (score 6):

Using GORM 2.0 This will work. Note the `.` has to be added for the `TablePrefix`.

```
func ConnectDB() (db *gorm.DB, err error) {
    db, err = gorm.Open(postgres.New(postgres.Config{
        DSN:                  `user=test password=test dbname=DB-NAME port=5432 sslmode=disable`,
        PreferSimpleProtocol: true,
    }), &gorm.Config{
        NamingStrategy: schema.NamingStrategy{
            TablePrefix:   "YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME.", // schema name
            SingularTable: false,
        }})
    return
}
```

Comment: it is important to make sure you  have the `.` in it.

Comment: where is the schema object coming from? `schema.NamingStrategy`

Answer (score 5):

To specify specific schema in your create statement modify your code like so:

```golang
dbVeiculosGorm.Table("schema.tablename").Create(&model.Veiculo{Placa: veiculo.Placa, Nome: veiculo.Nome}
```

To specify schema for your migrate action, add this method:

```golang
type Veiculo struct {
    gorm.Model
    Codigo int    `json:"vei_codigo"`
    Placa  string `json:"vei_placa"`
    Nome   string `json:"vei_nome"`
}

func (u *Veiculo) TableName() string {
    // custom table name, this is default
    return "schema.veiculo"
}
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. The other answers are for table prefixing which isn't what the question is.

Answer (score 3):

before automigrate do

```
gorm.DefaultTableNameHandler = func(dbVeiculosGorm *gorm.DB, defaultTableName string) string {
    return "your schema name." + defaultTableName
}

dbVeiculosGorm.AutoMigrate(&model.Veiculo{})
```

Comment: I get the following error `DefaultTableNameHandler not declared by package gorm`

Answer (score 3):

The Answer of **@hbswift** also worked for me but I tried something before which is a little bit different inspired by latest gorm Close idea.

```
func ConnectDB() (db *gorm.DB, err error) {
    db, err = gorm.Open(postgres.New(postgres.Config{
        DSN:                  `user=postgres password=a12345 dbname=YOUR-DB-NAME port=5432 sslmode=disable`,
        PreferSimpleProtocol: true, // disables implicit prepared statement usage. By default pgx automatically uses the extended protocol
    }), &gorm.Config{})
    return
}


func main() {
    var sqlDB *sql.DB
    var db *gorm.DB
    {
        var err error
        db, err = ConnectDB()
        if err != nil {
            os.Exit(-1)
        }
        sqlDB, _ = db.DB()
        sqlDB.Exec(`set search_path='Schema-Name'`)
    }
    defer sqlDB.Close()

}
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. The other answers are for table prefixing which isn't what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to **Alan.WCR** to Capitalize Table name,

```
gorm.DefaultTableNameHandler = func(db *gorm.DB, table string) string {
    var tableName string
    names := strings.Split(table, "_")
    for _, name := range names {
        tableName = tableName + strings.Title(name)
    }
    return "Users." + tableName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this configuration with my database with singular names with postgresql.

```
gorm.DefaultTableNameHandler = func(db *gorm.DB, table string) string {
    fmt.Printf(table)
    return "schema_name." + table[:len(table)-1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment yet or I would comment on Yurifull's post. It is worth mentioning that singularizing is a big more complex than chopping off the last character. Fortunately, jinzhu has split the singularization logic out into its own package so we can update Yurifull's code to look like:

```
import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/inflection"
)

...

gorm.DefaultTableNameHandler = func(db *gorm.DB, table string) string {
    fmt.Printf(table)
    return "schema_name." + inflection.Singular(table)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the latest version of gorm this WILL not work:

```golang
gorm.DefaultTableNameHandler = func(dbVeiculosGorm *gorm.DB, defaultTableName string) string {
    return "your schema name." + defaultTableName
}

dbVeiculosGorm.AutoMigrate(&model.Veiculo{})
```

Instead define your naming convention in the gorm config. Example:

```golang
    dsn := "host=localhost user=myuser dbname=golang_tutorial port=5432"
    db,err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
            NamingStrategy: schema.NamingStrategy{
                TablePrefix: "golang_crud.", // schema name  
                SingularTable: true,
            },
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

> Please check with this code my testing is on

package main

import (
"github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
_ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)

type User struct {
ID       int
Username string
}

func main() {
db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5432 sslmode=disable dbname=aman")
if err != nil {
panic(err)
}
defer db.Close()
db.LogMode(true)

```
// set schema here.
gorm.DefaultTableNameHandler = func(db *gorm.DB, tableName string) string {
    return "s1." + tableName
}

db.CreateTable(&User{})
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Here's a basic example of pretty much all you need to insert some simple data
 into a **PostgreSQL** database via **gorm**.

> main.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres" // Don't forget the dialect
)

// Simple Example model
type FuelType struct {
    gorm.Model // Gorm default columns (id, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at)
    Name string
}

func main() {
    // Database initialization
    db, err := gorm.Open(
        "postgres",
        "host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres dbname=foo password=bar sslmode=disable",
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Can't connect to the db: ", err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := db.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln("Can't close the db connection: ", err)
        }
    }()

    // Migration
    db.AutoMigrate(&FuelType{})

    // Insertion
    fuelType := FuelType{Name: "100 GFuel"}
    db.Create(&fuelType)
}
```

Comment: I've tried just like your example but doesn't work. My db has multiple schemas. How I set the specific schema that I want to insert the data?

Comment: What is your OS? Have you setup your user authentication to use password instead of identity? It's normal to have multiple schemas, they come by default.

Comment: it is w10. I've already create, update, delete and get data from database. Now I'm trying to use the gorm package to simplify things...

Comment: OK so you're sure your user has **authentication via password and not identity**? If you copy-paste my code in a new file, change the credentials and run it. Does it insert into your db?

Comment: It runs, but does not insert in to db!!

Comment: I found where the data is saved. This example create a new table in PUBLIC SCHEMAS. I'm trying to save data in a schema that already exist, just a row with firstname, lastname, age etc...How can I do this? @Mihailo

Comment: This seems like an example that does not fix the issue mentioned in the question but instead does something in the public schema.